# Regular expression in c# to extract data

Tags: c#, regex

I want to extract the numbers from the string. I have two strings as below.

```
1_09-Sep-14#200
```

For the above string I am using the following expression but its not properly working, I want to get the `1` after `09-Sep-14` and then `200`.

```
string S = "1_09-Sep-14#200";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(S, "(?<=[_#])(\\d+)(?=[_#])?"))
{
    string s = Convert.ToString(m.Groups[1]);
}
```

I would like to use the regular expression for the this string as well.

```
1_4-11#100
```

Comment: How about `foreach (string s in S.Split('_', '#')) { ... }`?

Comment: Wow, thats the easier way... I didn't think about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=[_#]|^)([0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?=[_#]|$)
```

Try this.

I have included `^` for capturing the first digit before `_` and `$` to capture last digit after `#`.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/29

Comment: I have tried, but its not working, error giving at \da

Comment: @user1650894 try (?<=[_#]|^)([0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?=[_#]|$)

Comment: @user1650894: when you write backslashes, use the verbatim format to enclose the string: `string pattern = @"(?<=[_#]|^)([\da-zA-Z-]*)(?=[_#]|$)";` or escape the backslash: `string pattern = "(?<=[_#]|^)([\\da-zA-Z-]*)(?=[_#]|$)";`. However writing `(?<=[_#]|^)([0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?=[_#]|$)` is better here since you only need ascii digits.